# Override sylius customerController

Tags: php, overriding, sylius

I find sylius.controller.customer base on `Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController` , I need to extend this class, when I looked at https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.2/customization/controller.html to create a CustomerController.php in the src\AppBundle and add its actions in the app/config/config.yml, when open my project in a browser, get this error:

> Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Controller\CustomerController":
> argument "$metadata" of method
> "Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController::__construct()"
> references interface
> "Sylius\Component\Resource\Metadata\MetadataInterface" but no such
> service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?

What's wrong with me?

`AppBundle\Controller`:

```
    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Sylius\Component\Resource\ResourceActions;


    class CustomerController extends ResourceController
    {
        public function createAction(Request $request): Response
        {
        $configuration = $this->requestConfigurationFactory->create($this->metadata, $request);

        $this->isGrantedOr403($configuration, ResourceActions::CREATE);
        $customer = $this->newResourceFactory->create($configuration, $this->factory);

        $form = $this->resourceFormFactory->create($configuration, $customer);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            $newResource = $form->getData();

            $event = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPreEvent(ResourceActions::CREATE, $configuration, $newResource);

            if ($event->isStopped() && !$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
                throw new HttpException($event->getErrorCode(), $event->getMessage());
            }
            if ($event->isStopped()) {
                $this->flashHelper->addFlashFromEvent($configuration, $event);

                if ($event->hasResponse()) {
                    return $event->getResponse();
                }

                return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToIndex($configuration, $newResource);
            }

            if ($configuration->hasStateMachine()) {
                $this->stateMachine->apply($configuration, $newResource);
            }

            $this->repository->add($newResource);
            $postEvent = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchPostEvent(ResourceActions::CREATE, $configuration, $newResource);

            if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
                return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, View::create($newResource, Response::HTTP_CREATED));
            }

            $this->flashHelper->addSuccessFlash($configuration, ResourceActions::CREATE, $newResource);

            if ($postEvent->hasResponse()) {
                return $postEvent->getResponse();
            }

            return $this->redirectHandler->redirectToResource($configuration, $newResource);
        }

        if (!$configuration->isHtmlRequest()) {
            return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, View::create($form, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST));
        }

        $initializeEvent = $this->eventDispatcher->dispatchInitializeEvent(ResourceActions::CREATE, $configuration, $customer);
        if ($initializeEvent->hasResponse()) {
            return $initializeEvent->getResponse();
        }

        $view = View::create()
            ->setData([
                'configuration' => $configuration,
                'metadata' => $this->metadata,
                'resource' => $customer,
                $this->metadata->getName() => $customer,
                'form' => $form->createView(),
            ])
            ->setTemplate($configuration->getTemplate(ResourceActions::CREATE . '.html'))
           ;

           return $this->viewHandler->handle($configuration, $view);
       }
   }
```

`app\config\config.yml`:

```
    sylius_customer:
       resources:
        customer:
            classes:
                controller: AppBundle\Controller\CustomerController
```

Comment: There is no sylius.controller.customer and CustomerController in Sylius at all. What do you trying to achieve? Maybe there are better way for your situation

Comment: I want to change the way of registration, using mobile phone number plus verification code to register, without password。But I found the original way to register was to go sylius.controller.customer:createAction , and I found that  sylius.controller.customer  based class is Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController ，So I'm going to rewrite customer based on ResourceController。